# Indexing and printing tuples

Tags: python, indexing, tuples

I'm using items() to return a tuple as follows:

```
(u'sigh', {'neg_tweets': 2, 'total_tweets': 2, 'pos_tweets': 0})
```

I would like to index the tuple and return the text and neg_tweets - pos_tweets like this:
sigh 2

However I cannot index the tuple. I'm printing as follows:

```
for term in new_terms.items():
    print  term
```

If I print term[0] I get 'sigh', but if I print term[1] I get {'neg_tweets': 2, 'total_tweets': 2, 'pos_tweets': 0} and I can't index it any further.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just index it as you would any dictionary, for example

```
term[1]['total_tweets']
```

Which would return

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

`term` is a tuple. However `term[1]` is a dictionary:

```
>>> term = (u'sigh', {'neg_tweets': 2, 'total_tweets': 2, 'pos_tweets': 0})
>>> type(term)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> type(term[1])
<class 'dict'>
```

You can access the dictionary by doing a `get()` on its keys.:

```
>>> term[1].get('neg_tweets')
2
>>> term[1].get('pos_tweets')
0
```

If you are not sure what keys it contains, you can iterate through its keys this way:

```
>>> for k, v in term[1].items():
...     print(k, v)
...
```

prints:

```
total_tweets 2
pos_tweets 0
neg_tweets 2
```

PS: A dictionary is unordered so the order of the keys are different.